# CDI & JPA: Best scope for repository classes

Tags: java-ee-6, cdi, scopes

I'm wondering what would be the most efficient (in terms of needed resources) scope for a repository class in CDI. Imagine the following scenario:

```
@RequestScoped
//OR @ApplicationScoped OR @SessionScoped OR @ConversationScoped?
public class SomeRepository{
  @Inject 
  private EntityManager em;

  public SomeClass getSomeClassById(int id){
    return em.createNamedQuery("getSomeClassById",SomeClass.class).
             setParameter("id",id).getSingleResult();
   }
}
```

The EntityManager in ths example is produced with a `@RequestScoped` scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question I think. Unexpectedly I can't think of anything that makes these classes special. So I would make them `@ApplicationScoped` as a new instance would function exactly the same as the one I just discarded. Not sure it would have any noticeable impact on the heap, probably not but maybe if they had to be recreated a lot?

I think it's fine to go with what conceptually feels more right for you.

Comment: But @ApplicationScoped means "only one instance per application" right? Would that cause this class to be a bottlneck if thousands of requests would be received at once?

Comment: @user1727072 no not at all. There's no concurrency management built into the scope. In this case it would also be thread safe since you inject only a proxy to the real entitymanager and each invocation will be forwarded to the correct instance. ApplicationScoped is the singleton pattern - everyone use the same instance possibly at the same time

Comment: iirc the @Singleton from EJB is threadsafe by default, perhaps this is what you are thinking of.